# Moment js Time Ago calculate wrong date

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, timeago

maybe a simple question but i don't get it.

```
var date = new Date();
test = date.toISOString();
alert(moment(test, "YYYYMMDD").fromNow());
```

Will return "16 hours", but why?

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5jacaxbf/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you are using [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), instead of [`moment(String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) ([`toISOString()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-iso-string/) output is *obviously* in ISO 8601 format) or [`moment(Date)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/).

So `moment(test, "YYYYMMDD")` will be the start of the day instead of the current time.

As the [Default](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/defaults/) section states:

> You can create a moment object specifying only some of the units, and the rest will be defaulted to the current day, month or year, or 0 for hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

```js
var date = new Date();
test = date.toISOString();
var m1 = moment(test, "YYYYMMDD")
console.log(m1.format());
console.log(m1.fromNow());
var m2 = moment(test)
console.log(m2.format());
console.log(m2.fromNow());
var m3 = moment(date)
console.log(m3.format());
console.log(m3.fromNow());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```